# logrotate is unable to list the created files in linux

Tags: cron, logrotate

```
   i created my logrotate in /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog 
        /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log
        {
               maxsize 100k
               minsize 100k
               hourly
               rotate 7
               postrotate
                    service rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
               endscript
}
```

After running i could see when i execute the command sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf

```
considering log /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-2018060617'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.7 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.8 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.6 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.7 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.5 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.6 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.4 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.5 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.3 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.4 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.2 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.3 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.1 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.2 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.0 to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.1 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
renaming /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log to /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.1
creating new /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log mode = 0644 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log: " 
            service rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
"
removing old log /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.8
error: error opening /var/log/pcapcapture/capture.log.8: No such file or directory
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

but why i am not able to view in the directory can some one help me

moved from a comment so output could be formatted:

```
/bin/ls -ld /var/log 
drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog 4096 Jun 7 10:17 /var/log 
/usr/bin/id uid=1000(alethea) gid=1000(alethea),groups=1000(alethea),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),130(wireshark)
```

Comment: Please add details "not able to view"? What tool? What are you trying? Edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1044126/edit ) your question and show us `/bin/ls -ld /var/log;/usr/bin/id`

Comment: i am not able to view the created logrotated files /bin/ls -ld /var/log drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog 4096 Jun  7 10:17 /var/log
/usr/bin/id uid=1000(alethea) gid=1000(alethea) groups=1000(alethea),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),130(wireshark)

Comment: @waltinator  i am trying to capture packets through tshark and sending to filebeat(Elastic stack) since my capture file grows i want to rotate file and delete the older ones

Comment: Please add details "not able to view"? What tool?